# Tic-tac-toe ANN player with TensorFlow learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, tic-tac-toe

I am experimenting with ANNs as tic-tac-toe players using [TensorFlow learn](http://terrytangyuan.github.io/2016/03/14/scikit-flow-intro/) (formerly Scikit Flow)

The simulator code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/bachi76/tic-tac-toe). My current simple nn-based player scores around 90% vs. a random player, but cannot defend at all, as I don't know how to feed into the NN what it should *not* do (wrong moves if the opponent has two in a row). Also, it only trains on the last board state and winning move.

Questions:

1. What would be a better approach to solve this problem (using an ANN and zero game rule knowledge)?
2. I assume an RNN/LSTM NN would help. There's a short example on the TensorFlow Learn site:

`classifier = skflow.TensorFlowRNNClassifier(rnn_size=EMBEDDING_SIZE, 
    n_classes=15, cell_type='gru', input_op_fn=input_op_fn,
    num_layers=1, bidirectional=False, sequence_length=None,
    steps=1000, optimizer='Adam', learning_rate=0.01, continue_training=True)`

But I'm at a loss here - how does this work for the tic-tac-toe example? What would the `rnn_size=EMBEDDING_SIZE` and `input_op_fn params` be?

Edit: The training code looks like this ([Player source](https://bitbucket.org/bachi76/tic-tac-toe/src/5d901d3886983ea0f3ac7f91e02290d092c64ab6/AIPlayer.py?fileviewer=file-view-default)):

```
def train(self, history):

    X = np.zeros((len(history), 18))
    y = np.zeros((len(history), 1))
    i = 0

    for game in history:

        # Train only on wins of player A (+1 values)
        if game.state == game.WIN_P1:

            # Get the second last board states (that lead to the winning move)
            X[i] = np.concatenate([
                game.history[-2],
                game.history[-3]
            ]).flatten()

            y[i] = game.last_move

        # TODO: How can we train lost games with a DNN classifier?
        # if game.state == game.WIN_PMINUS1:

        i += 1

    self.classifier.fit(X, y)
```

So a row in X contains the last two game states (3x3 nparrays containing 0, 1, -1 for empty, player 1, player 2 respectively), and y contains the last move (that lead to the victory).

Comment: Without a precise description of your dataset used to train your ANN, it's hard to help (how are random-playouts transformed to train-data; random-playouts also have their weaknesses regarding learning). In general this is more of a domain for reinforcement-learning instead of supervised-learning. And i also don't see the point in RNN/LSTM NNs. With a good RL-based system, a simple feed-forward network will be enough (AlphaGo also used Feed-forward networks).

Comment: @sascha I've added the data info and training code of the currrent DNN. But as said, this was just a first experiment. I started writing a DQL player now using "deep" reinforcement learning. Still (as this is meant as experimenting lab for various ANNs) I wonder how one would go about an RNN/LSTM - which hopefully can consider the move sequence, not just the last move(s) flat.

Comment: Saw this related stuff on the web: https://github.com/amrqura/TicTacTeoNeuralNetwork